# How to prove that $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^5+x-3\rangle$ is not an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, integral-domain

How to prove that $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^5+x-3\rangle$ is not an integral domain?

I have used sage to get

sage: x = PolynomialRing(RealField(), 'x').gen()

sage: f = x^5+x-3

sage: f.factor()

$(x - 1.13299756588507) * (x^2 - 0.950761513339099*x + 1.50221285149526) * (x^2 + 2.08375907922416*x + 1.76262856840348)$

How to use a general trick to prove it without using any tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a finite-dimension algebra over a field, so if it is a domain, it is [an algebraic field extension](/questions/146857).  But there are no field extensions of degree 5 over $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and degree 2 over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Use the fact that every polynomial in $\mathbb R[x]$ is a product of quadratic and linear terms.

Comment: Done!! What a fool I am!! :(

Comment: @Hunter: Depending on your taste (i.e., what you'd like to call elementary), there is an even more elementary argument of the same flavor: every odd-degree polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ has a real root by the intermediate value theorem.